# jquery ajax call to jsp page input undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am calling a JSP page through jQuery that handles downloading files.

```
$("#download").click(function(e){
    $.get("download.jsp", {filename:"file.txt"},doUpdate());
});
```

and my doUpdate() is

```
function doUpdate(response){
    console.log('done with jsp ' + response);
}
```

response is undefined

I know the JSP page is working because if I hard code the filename the page executes correctly.

In the jsp I get the filename using:

```
String filename = request.getParameter("filename");
```

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your referencing the handler function badly

```
$.get("download.jsp", {filename:"file.txt"},doUpdate());
```

Should be

```
$.get("download.jsp", {filename:"file.txt"},doUpdate);
```

If you leave the () you are executing the function and it's the return value which get passed as argument to the get method

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you aren't passing the data to the function, try:

```
$.get("download.jsp", {filename:"file.txt"}, doUpdate);
```

or

```
$.get("download.jsp", {filename:"file.txt"}, function(data) {
  doUpdate(data);
  // more stuff
});
```